# Cannot resolve :spring-securty-core:2.0-RC2 in grails 2.3.7

Tags: java, spring, grails

I've tried following the various threads about spring-security-core 2.0, but I cannot get it added. This is the error message I'm getting

> | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact
>   org.grails.plugins:spring-securty-core:zip:2.0-RC2 in grailsCentral
>   (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the
>   full trace) | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not
>   find artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-securty-core:zip:2.0-RC2 in
>   grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use
>   --stacktrace to see the full trace) | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact
>   org.grails.plugins:spring-securty-core:zip:2.0-RC2 in grailsCentral
>   (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the
>   full trace) | Error Could not find artifact
>   org.grails.plugins:spring-securty-core:zip:2.0-RC2 in grailsCentral
>   (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) | Run 'grails
>   dependency-report' for further information.

This is my BuildConfig.groovy file, minus the comments:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" /
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6

grails.project.fork = [
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
    }
    log "error"
    checksums true
    legacyResolve false

    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()

        mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }

    dependencies {
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.30'
    }

    plugins {
        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'
        compile ':spring-securty-core:2.0-RC2'
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.4"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.7"
    }
}
```

- Grails 2.3.7
- JDK 1.7.0u55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a typo in the security word, can you try using this instead:

```
compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
```